# Nightwatch.js How to Paste?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightwatch.js

Is there any way to paste text using Nightwatch?

```
var host = 'http://google.com';
   module.exports = {
        'New product': function(client) {
            client
                .url('https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp')
                .pause(5000)
                .click('#main > div.tooltip.w3-mobile > button')
                .pause(2000)
                .url(host)
                .click('#lst-ib')
                .pause(2000)
                .keys(client.Keys.LEFT_CONTROL, "v") //doesn't work
                .pause(10000)
                .end();
        }
    };
```

I used this code but it doesn't work. Help

Comment: Hmmmmm what? More please

Comment: ok, i need to paste copied text using nightwatchjs. Is there ant way?

Comment: does it work if you just use `client.Keys.CONTROL`?

Comment: it doesn't work with `client.Keys.CONTROL`

Comment: What is your test case?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking the element you're expecting actually has focus first?  #lst-ib in this case.  Then do the following?  It should work unless you've done something weird with that client definition

```
.keys([client.Keys.CONTROL, 'v']);
```